# Append query string using htaccess URL rewrite not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this Apache Rewrite rules:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !lang
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(jp|en|kr|cn)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.example.com/$1&lang=%1 [L, QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(jp|en|kr|cn)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.example.com/$1?lang=%1 [L, QSA]
```

What I expected is

1. `http://en.example.com` to `http://en.example.com?lang=en`
2. `http://en.example.com/list.php` to `http://en.example.com/list.php?lang=en`
3. `http://en.example.com/product.php?id=1` to `http://en.example.com/product.php?id=1&lang=en`

(1) and (2) is fine, but what I got for (3) is

`http://en.mobile-wifi_rental.local/product.php&lang=en?id=1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one rule for this, here it is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !lang
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(jp|en|kr|cn)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.example.com/$1?lang=%1 [L,QSA]
```

The problem with your first rule was the use of `&` instead of `?` for the query string.

A generic version of it would be:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !lang
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z]{2})\.[^\.]+\.[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1?lang=%1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: In my case, it doesn't need to be generic. I can use the exact country codes (`jp|en|kr|cn`) and domain (`example.com`).

Comment: It tried your generic rule at http://htaccess.mwl.be/. `id=1` is not appended for `http://en.example.com/product.php?id=1`. The result is `http://en.example.com/product.php?lang=en`. What I want is like `http://en.example.com/product.php?id=1&lang=en`

Comment: Yes, I only need one rule and it works on the real live server, the online tester http://htaccess.mwl.be/ is not just working as expected.

Comment: That's right I also tested it on the online tool that doesn't quite work as a real server.

Answer (score 1):

I changed your rules, `%{QUERY_STRING}` added manually:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !lang
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(jp|en|kr|cn)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^$ http://%1.example.com/?lang=%1   [L,QSA]

#Rule for empty query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(jp|en|kr|cn)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%1.example.com/$1?lang=%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !lang
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(jp|en|kr|cn)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%1.example.com/$1?%{QUERY_STRING}&lang=%1 [L]
```

Tested with string: `http://en.example.com/product.php?id=1` and the result is `http://en.example.com/product.php?id=1&lang=en`

Comment: It almost works. I tried yours at http://htaccess.mwl.be/ for `http://en.example.com/product.php`. The output result is `http://en.example.com/product.php?&lang=en` with extra `&`

Comment: Because it needs and extra rule to check if query_string is empty.

Comment: @Sithu I added an extra rule to verify if query string is empty. Tested!

Comment: Thanks, but then what is the difference between the first rule and the third rule?

Comment: And without `!lang` it will cause redirect loop.

Comment: The online tester htaccess.mwl.be is not just working as expected.

Comment: Can you write the test cases and expected results?